# Custom Color Calendar in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, calendar

I have used Bci Calendar for the representation of my "Posted Date" and "Amount". I want to give "Blue" color to all the weekdays and "Red" color to weekends (Sat and Sun) to determine amount posted on weekend. But by default I can only see color to put on minimum and maximum value. Is there any other visual for better representation of Amount on weekday and weekend or any way to add required color formatting in Bci Calendar?

I have tried to make custom calendar but it's not the best representation and also time consuming.